# Sometimes, the console hangs,

Tags: c++, console

I make socket console program.
c++ server, and client.
Sometimes, when client sends a message, the server does not react.
So I hit the enter to the console of the server, it works well again.
Not often, just sometimes it happens.

The server console has no 'keyboard input method', which is just showing out the message from the client.

Why is it happened?
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you flush the buffer often enough?

Comment: Could you post you code ,to make things more clear .

Comment: Based on this information, I can tell that there may be something wrong with your implementation. Have you tried looking into that? Or maybe you have an unreliable connection.